# How to add process definitions to JBPM RuntimeManager at runtime?

Tags: jbpm, apache-storm

We are working on an application in which a user can design his own workflow (in a web-ui) and then submit it for execution. We have chosen jBPM as our execution and workflow manager engine. The user submitted workflow will be translated to a jBPM (bpmn2) workflow. We are working with version 6.1.0.Final. Since this is a multi-user application, supporting concurrent workflows execution is a primary requirement. To facilitate that we are building jBPM on top of storm, where, for instance, each submitted workflow (fed by the spout) will execute in a separate bolt.

After going through the docs again we figured out that it makes sense to use per process instance that instructs runtime manager to maintain a strict relationship between kie session and process instance. Although after looking at couple of more examples and code snippets we are confused on what is the correct approach to get a *KieSession* instance. So far we have seen two approaches:

1.

```
# Get a new KieBase and KieSession for every workflow submitted.  
KieHelper kieHelper = new KieHelper();  
KieBase kieBase = kieHelper  
                .addResource(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("MyProcess.bpmn"))  
                .build();  
KieSession ksessionFromBase = kbase.newKieSession();
```

2.

```
# using same manager instance for all workflows; get a new session    
manager = (RuntimeManager) applicationContext.getBean("runtimeManager"); # per process instance runtime manager  
RuntimeEngine engine = manager.getRuntimeEngine(ProcessInstanceIdContext.get());  
KieSession ksessionFromEngine = engine.getKieSession();
```

In first approach, we need to create new *KieBase* and *KieSession* for every workflow submitted. Also this approach doesn't use runtime environment or runtime manager or runtime engine. In second approach, we create a per-process-runtime-manager and get a new session out of it for every workflow submitted. But with this approach we don't know how to add a process definition at runtime.

Moreover, the documentation leans towards the usage of runtime manager and we dont really know the advantage/disadvantage of not going through that route and above that the issue of adding a process definition.

Any clarifications would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had same problem and I used KnowledgeBuilder approach to create a new KieBase from the builder each time I add a new process definition:

Sample:

```
static {
    //TODO remove when fixed: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-4378
    ProcessNodeBuilderRegistry.INSTANCE.register(ActionNode.class, null );
}
private final KnowledgeBuilderImpl knowledgeBuilder = (KnowledgeBuilderImpl) KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
private volatile KieBase kieBase = knowledgeBuilder.newKnowledgeBase();


public synchronized void addBpmnProcess(WorkflowProcess process){
    //TODO remove when fixed: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-4378
    new ProcessBuilderImpl(knowledgeBuilder).buildProcess(process, null);
    kieBase = knowledgeBuilder.newKnowledgeBase();

    // or  when adding only processes as  Process object
    //((KnowledgeBaseImpl)kieBase).addProcess(process);
}

protected synchronized void addBpmnProcess(Resource resource) {
    knowledgeBuilder.add(resource, ResourceType.BPMN2);
    kieBase = knowledgeBuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
}

public void addBpmnProcess(InputStream bpmnProcessDefinition) {
    addBpmnProcess(ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(bpmnProcessDefinition, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));
}
```

PS.  This is only a sample, especially related to synchronization :)

Answer (score 0):

The use of the Runtime Manager is the recommended one, because it set up all the services that you will probably need to work with a business process. So, as the documentation says, use the runtime manager. I would like to recommend you to take a look at the jbpm-kie-services project which is basically the layer providing the jBPM tooling, you should consider that as a blueprint on how to create your own application, because the goal that you described for your application is almost identical to the one provided by the jBPM Console NG.

Regards

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. You recommend the RuntimeManager approach. But the RuntimeManager approach from the question doesn't include logic to actually add a process to the preexisting manager, because the OP doesn't know how and is asking how to do it.